# Making if statement more efficient

Tags: python

Hi everyone I currently have a function that checks if a file exist and copies over the desired files into a folder via the shutil library, this is done by multiple "if" statements. How can I make my code more efficient ? I would like to only use one if statement if possible but I am not sure how to start

```
def files_to_copy():

    #History File Path
    source_history = 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\History' 
    
    #Cookies File Path
    source_cookie = 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Extension Cookies'
    
    #BookMark File Path

    source_bookMark = 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Bookmarks'

    #Where the Artifacts will be placed
    destination = 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\TracesGenerated'

# Check if Cookie File exist, if it exist copy into destination folder
    if os.path.exists(source_cookie):
        try:
            print ("File Exist, Cookies File Copied to Destination: " + destination)
            sourceCookieCopy =  source_cookie
            print("\n"+"Source Path:", "\n" + sourceCookieCopy)
            shutil.copy(sourceCookieCopy, destination)

        # If any errors occurs when copying files
        except shutil.Error:
            print("An Error has occurred while copying file.")

    else:
        print ("\n" + "Cookies File does not exist")
        print ("No Cookies File Copied" + "\n")
    
# Check if History File exist, if it exist copy into destination folder
    if os.path.exists(source_history):
        try:
            print ("History File Exist, History File Copied to Destination: " + destination)
            sourceHistoryCopy =  source_history
            print("Source Path:", "\n" + sourceHistoryCopy)
            shutil.copy(sourceHistoryCopy, destination)

        # If any errors occurs when copying files
        except shutil.Error:
            print("An Error has occurred while copying file.")
    else:
        print ("\n" + "History File does not exist")
        print ("No History File Copied" + "\n")
    
# Check if BookMark File exist, if it exist copy into destination folder
    if os.path.exists(source_bookMark):
        try:
            print ("\n"+ "BookMarks File Exist, BookMark File Copied to Destination: " + destination)
            sourceBookMarkCopy = source_bookMark
            print("Source Path:", "\n" + sourceBookMarkCopy + "\n")
            shutil.copy(sourceBookMarkCopy, destination)

        # If any errors occurs when copying files
        except shutil.Error:
            print("An Error has occurred while copying file.")
    else:
        print ("\n" + "BookMarks File does not exist")
        print ("No BookMarks File Copied" + "\n")
```

Comment: You can use a function

Comment: @SPSharan I believe I can write a function to check for the existing files first , please correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: Your performance is bounded more by your file checking than by how you're using if-else statements. Remember, you're checking that files exist. This may entail requests made against RAM or against an SSD or disk. In all of these cases, this time is much larger than the cost of an if statement

Comment: Asking for help improving a piece of code is a lot clearer if you tell us the actual requirements.

Comment: @khelwood I would like to check if a file exists and copy it into a folder, currently I have 3 separate "if" statements to check if the desired file exists before copying it into the folder and if it doesn't exist the user would be prompted with a message showing it doesn't exist. I would like to reduce the if statements and run it under a single function

Comment: these sort of questions probably fit more into https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple places, where you could save yourself hassle of repeating yourself, e.g. you can make your filepaths from a common root folder, and then you can check-and-copy the file using a distinct function

```
import os.path as osp

def copy_file(file_path, destination, print_label):
    if not osp.exists(file_path):
        print (f"\n{print_label} does not exist")
        print (f"No {print_label} copied\n")
        return
    
    try:
        shutil.copy(file_path, destination)
        print(f"File Exist, {print_label} Copied to Destination: " + destination)
        print(f"\nSource Path:\n{file_path}")
    except shutil.Error:
        print(f"An Error has occurred while copying {print_label}.")

def files_to_copy(user_dir_path):
    destination = osp.join(user_dir_path, 'Desktop', 'TracesGenerated')
    chrome_user_dir = osp.join(user_dir_path, 'AppData', 'Local', 'Google', 'Chrome', 'User Data', 'Default') 
    copy_file(file_path=osp.join(chrome_user_dir, 'History'),
              destination=destination, print_label='History File') 
    copy_file(file_path=osp.join(chrome_user_dir, 'Extension Cookies'),
              destination=destination, print_label='Cookies File')  
    copy_file(file_path=osp.join(chrome_user_dir, 'Bookmarks'),
              destination=destination, print_label='Bookmarks File')  

def main():
    files_to_copy('C:\\Users\\admin')
```

And just in case you would need to copy say 10 files, you could wrap it in a loop:

```
for path, label in [
    ('History'          , 'History File'),
    ('Extension Cookies', 'Cookies File'),
    ('Bookmarks'        , 'Bookmarks File'),
]:
    copy_file(file_path=osp.join(chrome_user_dir, path),
              destination=destination, print_label=label)
```

Answer (score 0):

Meta code, not quaranteed to work:
j

```py
def files_to_copy():
    from pathlib import Path

    # store all the files and "name" into list of tuples so that they can be looped 
    files_to_copy = [("Cookie", Path("C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Extension Cookies"),
                     ("History", Path("C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\History"),
                     ("Bookmarks", Path("C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Bookmarks")) ]
    destination = Path("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\TracesGenerated")

    # loop the above datastructure to eliminate the duplicate code
    for file_description, file_name in files_to_copy:
      if file_name.exists():
        shutil(file_name, destination)
        try:
            print(f"Source Path:\n {file_name}\n")
            shutil(file_name, destination)
            print(f"\n{file_description) File Exist, {file_description} File Copied to Destination: {destination}")
        except shutil.Error:
            print(f"An Error has occurred while copying {file_description} file.")
      else:
        print("\n{file_description} File does not exist")
        print("No {file_description} File Copied\n")
```